# C++ /C++11 assign another class implementation in the source code

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to achieve the following behavior

```cpp
struct A {
};

template <bool arg>
struct B = A; // ERROR: THIS IS NOT A VALID LINE

template <>
struct B<false> {
  // Specific implementation of B
};
```

In other words, if a template argument `arg` is `true` the `struct B` should match `struct A` exactly, otherwise I would like to provide my own implementation. Is there an elegant way to achieve that?

I can think of two possible approaches but neither attract me.

- A workaround with help of `using` clause. I don't like this because I had to rename a class that contains a specific implementation of `B`. I don't want to introduce another `struct C`. It still should be called `B` not `C`.

```cpp
struct A {
};

struct C {
  // Specific implementation of B
};

template <bool arg>
using B = typename std::conditional<arg, A, C>::type;
```

- Using `inheritance`. I don't like this approach because I want `struct B` to be an exact copy (alias) of `struct A` but not a derived class. Since constructors are not inherited I would probably have put extra lines to deal with that. All these extra lines do not bring any real functionality but just mimics the "assignment" operator that I need. Moreover, extra lines are source of possible overhead.

```cpp
struct A {
};

template <bool arg>
struct B : public A
{
};

template <>
struct B<false> {
};
```

P.S. I am inclined to to use another `namespace` and `using` clause together

```
struct A {
};

namespace arg_false {
  struct B {
    // Specific implementation of B
  };
}

template <bool arg>
using B = typename std::conditional<arg, A, arg_false::B>::type;
```

Comment: "I don't want to introduce another struct `C`. It still should be called `B` not `C`." Can you elaborate on why this? Using such a `C` would be the natural solution to your problem. Think of `C` as an implementation detail of `B`.

Comment: "I don't want to introduce another struct C." isn't a convincing reason not to take the approach that is the simplest, the natural one, and the least likely to raise eyebrows from readers.

Comment: Indeed, I was not clear here. The reason is that the real project has very different names but not `A`, `B` or `C`, in fact they are under different namespaces e.g. `A` is `a::b::c::general::SomeClassName` and `B` is `a::b::c::general::specific::SomeClassName`. So under certain conditions `B` is nothing but `general` implementation of a certain class. I am not very happy to introduce another namespace because it has nothing to do with the logic but just helps me to avoid name clashes.